# Fit a smooth curve in streamflow (discharge - m3/s) data

Tags: r

This is discharge data vs return period in hydrology. What type of smoothing can we use to better plot and represent discharge data. I have an attached my R_plot what I was able to do.

[image: low flow frequency curve in R]

What type of smoothing in ggplot is used for stream flow - discharge dataset?

I was wondering how to get other plot similar to attached image by changing axis scales.

[image: How to manipulate axis scale like this]

[image: How to get those type of scales in terms of 10]

| Flow | return_period |
| --- | --- |
| 1044 | 1 |
| 255 | 1.5 |
| 37 | 2 |
| 9.96 | 5 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 3.35 | 20 |
| 3 | 50 |

Comment: We don't know what your code is currently, but assuming you have a `scale_x_continuous`, you could change it to `scale_x_log10`. Same for the y axis.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: #**********Script for attached plot************
ggplot(lffc, aes(x = return_period, y = Flow, colour=Type))+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), conf.int = FALSE)+  #geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,1.5, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,50, 100, 500, 1000))+
  ggtitle("LFFC") +
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))+
  xlab("Return Period") +
  ylab("Stream Flow (m3/sec)") +
  theme_bw()
#****************************************

Comment: I simply manipulated axis value. I am interested in what particular smoothing from ggplot2 is used for smoothing streamflow discharge dataset?